# Error: Redirected when going from "/pages/login" to "/dashboard" via a navigation guard

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

Guys i don't know why im get this error when i try to login, console error after login is made:

> Error: Redirected when going from "/pages/login" to "/dashboard"
> via a navigation guard.

Im trying when i hit login to redirect me to /dashboard page after the validation is made but when i hit login it does nothing no redirect, and if i hit again the login button the redirect is made on dashboard page. Any solutions? Thanks!

```
loginJWT ({ commit }, payload) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      jwt.login(payload.email, payload.password)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
          // If there's user data in response
          if (response.data.userDetails) {
            // Navigate User to homepage
            router.push(router.currentRoute.query.to || '/') // <- Here is the redirect after login

            // Set accessToken
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.accessToken)

            // Update user details
            commit('UPDATE_USER_INFO', response.data.userDetails, {root: true})

            // Set bearer token in axios
            commit('SET_BEARER', response.data.accessToken)

            resolve(response)
          } else {
            reject({message: 'Wrong Email or Password'})
          }

        })
        .catch(error => { reject(error) })
    })
  }
```

In router js:

```
{
          path: '/dashboard',
          name: 'dashboard',
          component: () => import('./views/Dashboard.vue'),
          meta: {
            rule: 'editor',
            authRequired: false
          }, 
          beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            guard(to, from, next)
          }
              }
```

And the guard code that validate the token after each route:

```
const guard = function (to, from, next) {
  // check for valid auth token
  const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
  axios.post('http://localhost:8081/api/users/checkAuthToken', {tokn: token})
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        next()
      }  
    }).catch(function (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        alert('access neautorizat')
        next('/pages/login')
        localStorage.removeItem('userInfo')
        localStorage.removeItem('accessToken')
      } 
    })
}
```

beforeEach code:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  
  const publicPages = [
    '/pages/login', 
    '/pages/register', 
    '/pages/forgot-password', 
    '/pages/comingsoon', 
    '/pages/error-404', 
    '/pages/error-500', 
    '/pages/not-authorized', 
    '/pages/maintenance', 
    '/callback'
  ]
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path)
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')

  if (authRequired && !loggedIn) {
    return next('/pages/login')
  }
  return next()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Set accessToken and Last Navigate User to homepage

Comment: that was the problem, i have to put the redirect after token access, thanks